# How can i get the path of the current user's "Application Data" folder?

Tags: c#, path, appdata

1)how can i find out the Windows Installation drive in which the user is working.? I need this to navigate to the **ApplicationData** in DocumentsandSettings.

2)Also how can i get the **user name** too so that i can goto ApplicaitionData.? Eg: "D:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data".

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Look at combining [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx) and [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to do this.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Answer (score 23):

Depending on what you are doing you might also want to look at

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

If the user is on a domain it will only be stored in their local `AppData` folder and not synced with their roaming profile.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the situation I needed to deal with. The stuff I need is indeed in AppData/Local and not AppData/Roaming, which is returned by default by this call

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [`Environment.SpecialFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData;
Environment.SpecialFolder.System
```

that should get you round the username requirement as well.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the System.Environment class and its properties and methods, e.g:

```
string systemDir = System.Environment.SystemDirectory;
string docs = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));

string systemDrive = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(systemDir);
```

The first one returns "**C:\Windows\system32**" for example and the second one "**C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\My Documents**".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1)how can i find out the Windows Installation drive in which the user
>   is working.?

```
    var systemDrive =  Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%systemdrive%");
```

> I need this to navigate to the ApplicationData in
>   DocumentsandSettings.

You don't really require to fetch the value of either system drive or currently logged in user name to achieve this. There are predefined environment variables `%localAppData%` and `%appData%` which give you fully qualified path of these directories as shown in the code below:

```
var localApplicationData = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%localappdata%"); 
//this gives C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local

var roamingApplicationData = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%appdata%");
//this gives C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming
```

> 2)Also how can i get the user name too so that i can goto
>   ApplicaitionData.? Eg: "D:\Documents and Settings\user\Application
>   Data".

Again, you don't need user name to get the application data path as I've discussed above. Still, for the sake of knowledge you can fetch it from `%username%` environment variable as shown below:

```
    var currentUserName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%username%");
```