# how to get users' application data folder using C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i get the path of the current user's “Application Data” folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915210/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-users-application-data-folder)

How can I get the Path of Current User's Application Data Folder?

Comment: I was not able to search the question in Stack Overflow but Google Provided me the solution on StackOveflow it self. [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915210/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-users-application-data-folder/915221)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```