# Why is my Delphi 6 program triggering a request for admin rights upon install on only a minority of Windows 7 systems (InnoSetup)?

Tags: windows, delphi, inno-setup, uac, user-permissions

I have a Delphi 6 program that for most users installs fine while running under a user account without admin privileges.  However, on some systems it triggers a request for admin rights.  Unfortunately mine isn't one of them so it's hard for me to diagnose this problem.  I use InnoSetup 5.1.9 to build my install programs.

How can I figure out what I need to change about my installation program's configuration to neutralize the need for admin rights on some people's systems?  It's causing trouble for my system because during installation, certain program data files are being copied into the *admin* account's application data folder.  Then when my program is launched under a *user* account, those files can not be found since they are not in the *user* account application folder, where they are expected to be.

Comment: Where is it being installed? (the directory)

Comment: @AustinHenley - To the application data folder.  In the minority case  when the user needs admin rights to install goes to C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\ during install and at run-time goes to C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Roaming\.  In most cases the directory is C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\ during install and runtime.

Comment: What OS are they using when it does work, also Windows 7?

Comment: In order to test your installer use a standard user. You are surely testing with an admin user.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan.  You're correct.  I was astonished to find out that I've been running an admin account this whole time with my Windows 7 64-bit partition.  I've create a standard user and I am retrying everything now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens due to default [`PrivilegesRequired`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_privilegesrequired.htm) directive value, which is, by default configured to require administrator elevation. If you don't need this, simply change in your InnoSetup script, value of this directive explicitly to something like this:

```
[Script]
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
```

From the reference:

> When **PrivilegesRequired** is set to **lowest**, Setup will not request to be
>   run administrative privileges even if it was started by a member of
>   the Administrators group. Additionally, the uninstall info root key
>   will always be HKEY_CURRENT_USER, and the "common" forms of the Shell
>   Folder constants are mapped to the "user" forms, even if
>   administrative privileges are available.

Comment: Why is it only triggering the request on only one of my Windows 7 user's PCs so far?  Is that a UAC setting that by default is lax on most Windows 7 boxes? I checked my InnoSetup script and I don't have an explicit PrivilegesRequired statement so you're right, it would be using the default level.

Comment: That most probably happen because that user have disabled UAC.

Comment: Ok.  I'll do a full retest using your suggestion and check in later.

Comment: @Robert Create a standard user for your testing. Your user account will be admin user.

Comment: @Robert, anyway I strongly recommend you to upgrade InnoSetup to the most recent version. You're using v.5.1.9 which is [`dated to 2006-12-10`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm). I'm quite lucky with my answer because just the version you're using introduced the change of a default `PrivilegesRequired` directive value to `admin`.

Comment: @TLama - Yes I saw that.  I upgraded right after reading your answer since I didn't see a "lowest" priveleges option in 5.1.9.  Working on a test build now, thanks.

Comment: @TLama - I'm already running into access denied errors using "lowest" privileges when Windows 7 tries to create the Program directory in the C:\Program Files(x86)\directory chain.  Any quick tips or am I in for the long haul on this one?

Comment: If you want to write to `Program Files` you have to run your setup elevated. The reason, why did authors made `admin` value as default was most probably because almost everyone wants to have application installed in `Program Files`.

Comment: @TLama - I'd like to try avoiding admin.  I notice that Chrome and other programs don't need admin rights to install.  Are they installing to app data local?  How do they do that and can you tell me the correct InnoSetup symbol for that directory? (e.g. - {app}, etc.)

Comment: Chrome is installed in the user's app data folder, which is in InnoSetup mapped to the [`{userappdata}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) constant. Anyway, are you going to let users choose a destination folder ? If so, you will have also count with an option that user can choose `Program Files` as destination, what would again fail your installer without elevation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17676/discussion-between-robert-oschler-and-tlama)

Comment: For reference, the reason it was working sometimes and not others is that 5.2.x was the first version that included the Vista elevation logic (since that was about when Vista first came out).  As a result of using an older version than that, Windows was deciding whether to elevate or not based on its own internal fuzzy heuristics, instead of being explicitly told one way or the other, which means that the results will vary depending on what hotfixes are installed or even what other installers had previously been run.  Upgrading to a more recent version fixes that.