# How to get "Application Data" folder path programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I have some legacy code that does some string concatenation to reach to the "Application Data" folder of the running PC. It has hard-coded strings like "C:\Documents and Settings\", "\Local Settings\Application Data\" etc.

The problem is it doesn't work on different versions of windows because of hard-coding.

Can I get this folder's path programmatically? May be by using an environment variable etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get the path of the current user's "Application Data" folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915210/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-users-application-data-folder)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, sometimes its just the right search string. I tried googling (using a different and much more verbose search string) and didn't get a proper link, so posted a question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get the directory of the `ApplicationData` folder (or any other [special system folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

```
var appDataPath
    = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum. There is one specifically for `ApplicationData`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

or

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Comment: You may want to explain what's a difference b/w `ApplicationData` and `LocalApplicationData`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
```

It just gives you enumerated data.. use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`
It gives you current user's AppData\Roaming folder