# setup project for visual studio application using advanced installer with local db data is retrieved but not saved in db

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

I am using advanced installer (simple) to create the setup project of a GUI i am making in visual studio. upon installation, it is possible to read data from the databse i.e the records that are already added can be read but as i try to save data in databse that function is not working and the application stops working. i think that the connection string is right that is why iam able to read data from it but why cant i update data. plz help.
the databse is is service-based local database

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if you have the database stored in the same install location as your application binaries. Usually that is a folder under Program Files.

You're application cannot write under this location when running as a standard user, and **it should never write/store data in that location**.

If you're not using the [Application Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915210/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-users-application-data-folder) folder to store your database, I suggest you update your app to do so, this should solve your problem.